# How to see if string contains substring when both string and substring are loaded dynamically on page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have found many help for 'string contain specific substring' when substring is known so we can specify like -     "Number".in(Str)) OR Str.indexOf("Number")

But in my case both String and sub string loaded at run time so i tried like -

```
function compareTables1(row,kk) {

 $('#table2 tr').each(function(p) {
     if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skip first row

    var customer = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
    if (customer.trim() == row.trim()) {
      checkme(this, kk);
    }       
     else
     {
         if (row.in(customer)) {  //why this does not work????
         alert("success sub str check");

     }}});   
  }
```

link to entire code is -
 http://jsfiddle.net/w7akB/55/

I am learning Jquery &  sure missing something small here.
thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using indexOf works.  When using indexOf, when value is -1 then it doesn't contain the string.

Its because you need to trim your string.  Updated fiddle works

```
if (customer.indexOf(row.trim()) > -1) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7akB/60/

Comment: I cant see it working. It does not go in loop.if  row.indexOf(customer) > -1)

Comment: @sana  You just forgot to trim the extra whitespaces in your strings.  I edited my answer and fiddle to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if one string is contained within another, the simplest way is to use the `indexOf()` function. That should work perfectly well when called with two variables that contain strings, so `customer.indexOf(row)` should work for you.

Note that if `row` isn't contained within `customer`, calling `indexOf()` will return -1. Therefore you'd want your `if` statement's condition to be:

```
if(customer.indexOf(row) != -1)
```

Comment: I tried the way suggest by Anthony & Wirey. but donno why the line - if("PhoneNumber".indexOf("Number") != -1){ //WORKS but not if specify as var name -  if (row.indexOf(customer) > -1) { //DOES NOT WORKS.